# Dynamically allocate array in C struct response incorrect?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, dynamic, malloc

I am trying to make two dynamically allocated arrays in C struct

```
typedef struct {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int *array1;
    int *array2;
    int check;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) test_T;

int main() {
    int data[8] = { 2, 3, 20, 21, 30, 31, 32, 100 };

    test_T *s_t = malloc(sizeof(s_t));
    s_t->array1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * s_t->count1);
    s_t->array2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * s_t->count2);

    s_t = (test_T *)data;
 
    printf("%d\n", s_t->check);

    return 0;
}
```

Both `array1` and `array2` sizes are unknown, respectively depend on `count1` and `count2`.

My struct data define in `main` function and put the data in my struct.
The problem is that `check` member in the structure is always `32`, but I want this value be `100`.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `test_T *s_t = malloc(sizeof(s_t));` --> `test_T *s_t = malloc(sizeof(*s_t));`

Comment: `s_t = (test_T *)data;`..then why do you `malloc()`?

Comment: Far too many issues in concept...can you tell what you want to achieve exactly? Seems to be a X-Y problem.

Comment: You are converting numbers into pointers and sizeof(test_T) is definitely not 8.

Comment: You are multiplying by count fields you never set to anything.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: changing seem to be the same problem. Becaus two arry size will depend on my data input first and seconds value(2 and 3). Then set the arry size to store later value(20 21 and 30 31 32).

Comment: @KeyuGan: I thinks this is a problem. But in my case, my data will not always be 8.

Comment: @ZanLynx: I change 's_t->array1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*s_t->count1);' --> 's_t->array1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);' the result seem to be the same.

Comment: `s_t = (test_T *)data;` does not make any sense. Please clarify your problem further.

Comment: Why do you use `int` for `count1` and `count2`? Why not `size_t`? Aren't they used to specify the len of an array?

Comment: You should not cast an array to a struct, especially not when the struct contains different data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- `__attribute__((packed))` is a system specific hack. Unless you know what you are doing and deem it absolutely necessary, you should not use such non-portable things.
- the size for the first `malloc()` is incorrect: `test_T *s_t = malloc(sizeof(s_t));` should be

  ```
    test_T *s_t = malloc(sizeof(*s_t));
  ```
- `s_t->count1` and `s_t->count2` must be initialized before they are used. The object returned by `malloc()` is uninitialized, so all structure members are uninitialized. It is unclear what the initial values of these members should be, 8 seems plausible.
- `s_t->check` is uninitialized. You should initialize it to `100` if this is the expected value.
- `s_t = (test_T *)data;` is bogus: you should instead copy the values from `data` to the arrays if that's what you want.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test_T {
    int count1;
    int count2;
    int *array1;
    int *array2;
    int check;
} test_T;

int main() {
#define DATA_COUNT  8
    int data[DATA_COUNT] = { 2, 3, 20, 21, 30, 31, 32, 100 };

    test_T *s_t = malloc(sizeof(*s_t));
    s_t->count1 = DATA_COUNT;
    s_t->count2 = DATA_COUNT;
    s_t->array1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * s_t->count1);
    s_t->array2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * s_t->count2);
    s_t->check = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; i++) {
        s_t->array2[i] = s_t->array1[i] = data[i];
    }
 
    printf("%d\n", s_t->check);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `memcpy()` for coping the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code but in this answers just one respond to one of them: Pointer vs Array

I think you misunderstand how pointers and structs work.
`array1` is a pointer. On AMD64 pointers have always 8 bytes. It does not depend on where they point to. On AMD64 your `Test_T` will use 28 bytes when the compiler does not add some padding.
When you alloc memory and store the pointer in `array1`, it means `array1` now points to a memory region that you reserved with `malloc()`.
`array1` nor `array2` are arrays, they are pointer. Maybe you choose a less misleading name for them?

> Both array1 and array2 sizes are unknown

This is wrong. They are pointers and the size of them are known. What is not unknown is the size of the memory region the are pointing to. This memory region can be used as an array, `array1` is not an array.

If you want to have a variable array inside your struct you have to place an array as last element with no size information and when you reserve memory for the struct you have to add the space for the array at the end and the struct. Only one variable array can be placed inside a struct.
All others need to be added with pointers.

Like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test_T
{
    int someOtherData;
    size_t count;
    int variableArray[];
};

int main(void)
{
    size_t count=5;
    struct Test_T *s_t=malloc(sizeof(*s_t)+sizeof(int)*count);
    //skipped malloc error handling, but you should do that in real programs 
    s_t->count=count;
    // .. some more code should be placed here ...
    free(s_t); //do not forget to free your allocated memory
}
```